# Find row with conversion error row in sql

Tags: sql-server, database

I need to find the error causing row from the table in sql, for example:

We have invoice table, if I need to convert the `Invoice date` column it results an error due to special character present at `Row ID` 4:

```
Row ID   INVOICE DATE   AMOUNT
1        05/22/2015     25
2        05/27/2015     85
3        05/17/2015     15
4        ,              28
```

My question is how to find the `Row ID` if invoice table has billion of data.
Is there any way to get the `Row ID`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use [**`ISDATE`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms187347.aspx) function

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid date, time, or datetime value;
>   otherwise, 0

```
select * 
from yourtable
where ISDATE([INVOICE DATE]) = 0
```

In `SQL Server 2012+` you can use [**`TRY_CONVERT`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function to do the conversion.

> Returns a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeds;
>   otherwise, returns null.

If the string is valid date then it will be converted to `date` else string will be converted to `NULL`

**Update:** Based on your comments

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE test_tab
    ([Row ID] int, [INVOICE DATE] varchar(10), [AMOUNT] int)
;

INSERT INTO test_tab
    ([Row ID], [INVOICE DATE], [AMOUNT])
VALUES
    (1, '05/22/2015', 25),
    (2, '05/27/2015', 85),
    (3, '05/17/2015', 15),
    (4, ',', 28)
;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT [Row ID],
        Try_convert(date, [INVOICE DATE]) AS [INVOICE DATE],
        amount,
        CASE
            WHEN Try_convert(date, [INVOICE DATE]) IS NULL THEN Concat('Row ID ', [Row ID], ' has some conversion issue')
            ELSE 'Valid Date'
        END AS comments
FROM   test_tab
```

**Result:**

```
╔════════╦══════════════╦════════╦════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Row ID ║ INVOICE DATE ║ amount ║              comments              ║
╠════════╬══════════════╬════════╬════════════════════════════════════╣
║      1 ║ 2015-05-22   ║     25 ║ Valid Date                         ║
║      2 ║ 2015-05-27   ║     85 ║ Valid Date                         ║
║      3 ║ 2015-05-17   ║     15 ║ Valid Date                         ║
║      4 ║ NULL         ║     28 ║ Row ID 4 has some conversion issue ║
╚════════╩══════════════╩════════╩════════════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: I have a table with huge data and with multiple dates  formats, simple select query takes more than 4 hrs , so if I Execute the query i need to get an error log than "Row id 4 has some conversion issue"  in Invoice Date column

Comment: @user2302158 - Do you want to return all the records or only the error records

Comment: @user2302158 - Also which version of `SQL Server` you are using

Comment: I need to return all the records, but  If an conversion error happens it should skip the entire row and also i need to know the skipped row Id ..

Comment: Oh... my... god... Super late comment here but I never knew of the TRY_ functions, these are life savers... the thought of how many hours spent over the years painstakingly sifting through rows and rows to find the one bad row and this was there since 2012... THANK YOU

Comment: @haag1 Glad it was helpful. I have been in similar situation, out of millions of rows one row will throw conversion error. Thank god for Try functions.

Answer (score 5):

I recently encountered a similar problem when casting strings with numeric values to a numeric data type. `ISNUMERIC()` wouldn't do, since it returns 1 for strings like `'-'` and `'-,'`, while a `CAST` fails on such values.

The technique shared above wouldn't work, since the column contained many Null values and empty strings, and these should be casted to `Null`

You can use [`PARSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parse-transact-sql) to track down the errors in such cases, since the error message for `PARSE` includes the value that caused the error. Then you can search for that value using a `WHERE` clause.